# How many homomorphisms $f\colon Z_{99} \to Z_{99}$ are there?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-homomorphism

I got this question earlier:

> How many homomorphisms $f\colon Z_{99} \to Z_{99}$ are there?

Which I answered with 100: First you have the identity homomorphism, and all it's shifts ($x\to x+1$, $x\to x+2$, ..., $x\to x+98$) for a total of $99$ homomorphisms.

Then all that's left is to add the trivial homomorphism: $f(x)=0$. Which brings the total up to $100$.

The answer just said $99$ though, so where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Shifts are *never* group-homomorphisms.

Comment: Think in terms of where the generator of $\mathbb Z_{99}$ can go. A homomorphism is determined by its action on a generating set.

Comment: @Gae.S. That one was a typo. 1 was supposed to represent the identity (0 in this case). Fixed now.

Comment: Hint: $\varphi:1 \mapsto n $, then $\varphi(x)=nx$.

Comment: @MitchellFaas What Gae. S. meant is that $\varphi(x)=x+c$ is not a homomorphism except when $c=0$. So your examples: $x\to x+1$ or $x \to x+2$ are NOT homomorphisms.

Comment: @AnuragA Yeah, I see that now.
The comment I made to them was about a typo in the trivial homomorphism. They deleted that comment though ^^

Answer (score 2):

There are $99$, each one determined by where you send a generator,  say $h(1)\in\Bbb Z_{99}$.

(If $h(1)=0$ you get the trivial one.)